# Wrong EFCore Entity Configuration for optional foreign key

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a EF Code First configuration:

```
    public class TaskLocationConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<TaskLocation>
    {
        public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<TaskLocation> b)
        {
            b.HasOne(x => x.TaskHeader)
                .WithMany(x => x.TaskLocations)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.TaskHeaderId);

            b.HasOne(x => x.SubArea)
                .WithMany(x => x.TaskLocations)
                .HasForeignKey(x=>x.SubAreaId)
                .IsRequired(false);

            b.HasOne(x => x.Workcenter)
                .WithMany(x => x.TaskLocations)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.SubAreaId)
                .IsRequired(false);
        }
    }
```

Class:

```
    public class TaskLocation 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int TaskHeaderId { get; set; }
        public TaskHeader TaskHeader { get; set; } 
        public SubArea SubArea { get; set; }
        public int? SubAreaId { get; set; }

        public Workcenter Workcenter { get; set; }
        public int? WorkcenterId { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to insert into table with SubAreaId only or with WorkcenterId only i get an error:

```
var location = new TaskLocation()
{
       CreateDate = DateTime.Now,
       WorkcenterId = workcenterId,
       TaskHeaderId = task.Id,
};
_context.Add(location);
```

ERROR:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_T_Locations_Workcenters_SubAreaId". The conflict occurred in database "DB_NAME", table "dbo.Workcenters", column 'Id'. The statement has been terminated.
```

SubAreaId and WorkcenterId should be optional... what is wrong with my configuration?

Comment: your subarea and workcenter are not nullable, this might be all it needs, also your workarea uses the same FK then your subarea in your configure call

Answer (score -1):

proper configuration

```
          b.HasOne(x => x.TaskHeader)
                .WithMany(x => x.TaskLocations)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.TaskHeaderId);

            b.HasOne(x => x.SubArea)
                .WithMany(x => x.TaskLocations)
                .HasForeignKey(x=>x.SubAreaId)
                .IsRequired(false);

            b.HasOne(x => x.Workcenter)
                .WithMany(x => x.TaskLocations)
                .HasForeignKey(x => x.WorkcenterId)  //<---- was SubAreaId here before 
                .IsRequired(false);
```

Comment: your welcome, this can happen to all of us^^